# How do I remove old ip address URL from Google search results?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, url, ip-address

I have a simple blog.

In google search engine page ranking, I notice it ranks the IP address URL of dev server. Whoops. However, the final site was moved to different server and is live there. Therefor, this IP address showing in Google serp does not work and should not be showing up in results. I have google console set up. In google results, it looks like this.

```
http://34.7.22.223/about/
```

I know using the Remove URL tool from google doesn't remove it from the search engines. It's a brand new site with no traction yet, so I'm not worried about redirects. I just want to remove this invalid link from google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this IP address showing in Google serp does not work

If by "does not work", you mean it doesn't resolve (as appears to be the case) then there is nothing you can do. But by the same token, there is nothing you need to do (since SEO is not a concern here) - the IP address will disappear from the SERPs soon enough.

> I know using the Remove URL tool from google doesn't remove it from the search engines.

However, this is something you *can* do. This is precisely what it does do - removes the page from the SERPs - providing the content is no longer available (which appears to be the case here).

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7041154

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I really misunderstood how the Google tool is used. Now I have a better understanding. I have submitted the URL to be removed and google scanned it and gave message to say they have confirmed the link is no longer active. Very nice.